Postman - Microsoft Graph beta/tenantRelationships/managedTenants/tenants - UnknownError 401 Unauthorized
I'm trying to write an automation that reads out all the managed tenants, their users and all the licenses they are actively using. One of the issues I'm having is getting the information through Postman.
I have a separate sync account with Global Admin privileges. If I login on Graph Explorer, grant consent to ManagedTenants.Read.All and query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/tenantRelationships/managedTenants/tenants it works and returns the data.
If I do the same in Postman, I get:

In Postman I'm using Grant Authorization Code with the Postman callback url set-up in the application. I logged in with the same account as on Graph Explorer, yet still I get an unauthorized error.

Admin consent is granted within the application for the whole organization.

Can you confirm whether you generated access token like this?

And the API permissions you have granted admin consent like this

Yes to both of those.

Do you mean on the seperate sync account? I added an Intune license to it, but that didn't change it. It already works in Graph Explorer though, so that would be weird.

So the sync account have a Intune license assigned?

@Rukmini Yes, it has.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions like below:

I generated access token using authorization code flow:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
grant_type:authorization_code
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default


Alternatively, you can make use of below API to get the customer ID:


Note that: To read the user information of the other tenant, the user must be the part of the tenant.

In TenantB, invite TenantA user:

TenantA  user must accept the invite:

Create a Microsoft Entra ID and assign User.Read.All delegated permissions:

Login with TenantA  user to generate the access token.
Generate the access token:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantBTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:TenantBAppID
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret


Now by using the above access token, TenantA can retrieve user information from TenantB

References:
azure - Is it possible to create a User (Microsoft Entra ID) for Tenant B from Tenant A? - Stack Overflow by me
List contracts - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
